# How to send particular content of pdf from VF Page in different languages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, language, conversion

I am sending an attachment using VF Page through batch class. I need to send Labels in PDF in different languages based on Account's organization values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Language attribute from `<apex:page>` tag like below.

```
<apex:page controller="controllerName" language="ja">
```

You can refer to [this document for more information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)

You can refer to [this post for your reference](https://www.sfdcstuff.com/2017/07/language-translation-in-visualforce-page.html)

Comment: Hi Samir, if we give language attribute, for all accounts it will send in same language right. Suppose If the batch class is sending emails of 20 accounts, Labels in Pdf should display in different languages based on their Account's org values. How do we check that condition?

Comment: use the variable for language attribute rather than hard coding the language in VF page and set it from apex class depending on you criteria. You can refer the post in the answer for your reference.